# Craft Personal for portfolio site

Tags: license

Can I use the free version of Craft for a portfolio site?  I know the free version of ee is for personal/non-profit sites only.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the features are sufficient, you can use it for whatever you want. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

See [pricing/edition overview page](https://buildwithcraft.com/pricing) and [license agreement](https://buildwithcraft.com/license) – neither puts any restrictions on what you can or can't use Craft Personal for.

Answer (score 2):

After reading "Built for personal sites built by and for the developer" on the pricing/overview page I too was wary but after asking Brandon directly via the Craft Slack he confirmed...

> yes totally fine, just please don't give your clients an Admin account

Comment: It's honestly not my intention to be rude here so please don't take it the wrong way, but a Client edition license is only $199 and I'd think that budget-wise, any commercial project should be able to accommodate that. Having a Client edition will probably save you a lot of headache if you're building a site for someone else :) Also - If the project is non-profit, keep in mind that P&T may give you a free or discounted Client/Pro license, see https://buildwithcraft.com/pricing

Comment: @mmikkel I agree, but my use case here is small holding page projects, where the client hasn't signed off a full project and wants a holding/landing etc page. I get the benefits of using my default Craft starter project with most stuff configured how I need, and I get to use twig for templating out _site/_base etc. Most of these project's end up being full Craft projects eventually anyway, it's just nice to know I'm not abusing the licence and having to fall back to doing everything completely statically.

Comment: – fair enough, just wanted to give my 2 cents and inform about the possibility of a free license, an option which everyone may not be aware of :)